# Qt Designer forms and QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qt-designer

How can you link a qtdesigner form from the QGIS itself, and to call a code made from the console?

Answer (score 5):

You can link a ui file directly to a table under Properties > Attribute Form, and select Provide ui-file from the top combobox.

You can dynamically load a ui to a Python class inheriting from QDockWidget:

```
self.ui = uic.loadUi(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myui.ui'), self)
```

Answer (score 5):

I designed a sample form in QtDesigner. Here is the form which contains one button:

[image]

In QGIS Python Console or Editor,

1. Load this form using `uic.loadUi`.
2. Define a method.
3. Connect this method to the button click event in the form.

```py
from qgis.PyQt import uic

# 1
form = uic.loadUi("c:/test/sample.ui")

# 2 
def load_shapefile():
    layer = QgsVectorLayer("c:/test/sample.shp", "Loaded_Layer", "ogr")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

# 3
form.pushButton.clicked.connect(load_shapefile)

form.show()
```

TEST:

[image]